# Quality of PNG file is poor

Tags: c#, graphics, png, system.drawing

Working on a project that requires me to create a shipping label and store it as PNG. I've setup the layout and everything looks good when I view the PNG file, but when I go to print on the thermal/ink jet/laser printer the quality is horrible.

I've searched all over but I can't find anything that seems to address my issue. I'm not a graphics person but I'm wondering if I need to build the file in a higher resolution, but the end result needs to be a 4 by 6 shipping label. What is the best method to improve the image quality?

Below is the code that is used to generate PNG file:

```
                Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("blanklabel.png");
                Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
                graphicImage.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                string dttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");

                // Create pen.
                Pen blackPen0 = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1);
                Pen blackPen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
                Pen blackPen2 = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
                Pen blackPen3 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

                //Top Rectangle - Draw Box
                Rectangle topRect = new Rectangle(5, 5, 367, 338);
                graphicImage.DrawRectangle(blackPen1, topRect);
                //Top Rectangle - Horizontial Lines
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 5, 41, 372, 41);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 5, 77, 372, 77);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen2, 5, 129, 372, 129);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen2, 5, 210, 372, 210);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen0, 5, 225, 372, 225);  //Draw row1 in middle
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen0, 5, 240, 372, 240);  //Draw row2 in middle
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen0, 5, 255, 372, 255);  //Draw row3 in middle
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 5, 271, 372, 271);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 5, 322, 372, 322);
                //Top Rectangle - Vertical Lines
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 258, 41, 258, 322);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 103, 210, 103, 271);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 172, 210, 172, 271);
                //graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 257, 210, 257, 271);                    
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 304, 210, 304, 271);

                //Top Rectangle - Label Text
                graphicImage.DrawString("Shipper's Information:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 43));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Receiver's Information:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 79));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Origin", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(263, 43));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Destination", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(263, 79));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Time-definite type", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(263, 131));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Total packages", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 213));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Total Actual weight", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 228));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Total Chargeable weight", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 243));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Freight Charges", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 258));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Additional Service", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(180, 213));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Charges", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(264, 213));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Total Charges", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(310, 213));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Payment Information:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 275));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Credit Account No.:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 290));
                graphicImage.DrawString("3rd Party District code:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 305));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Receiver's Signature:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(263, 275));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Delivery Date:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(263, 305));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Remarks:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 327));

                //Bottom Rectangle - Draw Box
                Rectangle bottomRect = new Rectangle(5, 349, 367, 211);
                graphicImage.DrawRectangle(blackPen1, bottomRect);
                //Bottom Rectangle - Horizontial Lines
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 258, 377, 372, 377);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 5, 401, 258, 401);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 5, 468, 372, 468);
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 5, 528, 372, 528);
                //Bottom Rectangle - Vertical Lines
                graphicImage.DrawLine(blackPen1, 258, 349, 258, 560);
                //Bottom Rectangle - Label Text
                graphicImage.DrawString("Shipment Type:", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(261, 352));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Description of Contents:", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(261, 380));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Declared value for Customs:", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(261, 420));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Country of Origin:", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(261, 450));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Shipper's Information:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 404));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Receivers's Information:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 471));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Total Charges:", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(261, 471));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Payment Information:", new Font("Arial", 6), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(261, 495));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Customer remarks:", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 538));
                //Bottom Rectangle - Self Drop Selection Box
                Rectangle bottomselectRect1 = new Rectangle(261, 538, 12, 12);
                graphicImage.DrawRectangle(blackPen1, bottomselectRect1);
                //Bottom Rectangle - Self Pickup Selection Box
                Rectangle bottomselectRect2 = new Rectangle(313, 538, 12, 12);
                graphicImage.DrawRectangle(blackPen1, bottomselectRect2);
                graphicImage.DrawString("Self-drop:", new Font("Arial", 5), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(276, 541));
                graphicImage.DrawString("Self-pickup:", new Font("Arial", 5), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(328, 541));

                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

                bitMapImage.Save("test_label_" + dttime + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                blackPen0.Dispose();
                blackPen1.Dispose();
                blackPen2.Dispose();
                blackPen3.Dispose();
                graphicImage.Dispose();
                bitMapImage.Dispose();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Printing a high quality 4x6" label on a 600dpi laser printer would require a bitmap that is 4*600 x 6*600 = 2400 x 3600 bitmap.  Yours is about 6 times too small.  Printing it at 4x6" anyway turns a pixel in the bitmap into a 6x6 blob of ink on the printer.  Sure, that looks pretty bad unless you have really long arms.

Comment: Thanks Hans, so to get me to my basic 96dpi I would need an image the size of 384X576. That gives me some direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but it may help. Here is what your image is:
Image Dinensions: 377 x 566 Pixels
10.19 x 15.30 Cm 
Pixels Per cm: 37
It might help to know what your output device(s) use, but most inkjet printers I have used are happy with 300 pixels per inch (or some multiple of 300 dpi). Other resolutions would have to be scaled, which could be disastrous for such fine detail.
Do you have a graphics program you can use to modify the resolution and scaling of your PNG so you can experiment without having to keep changing your program? (I'm using an ancient version of the no-longer-available Paint Shop Pro, but I also have Corel Photo Paint which would also do the job.) If you don't have anything, you might try gimp (free bitmap software).

Comment: Thanks for the input Tamias, the goal is to print the label to thermal printers which use 4X6 labels. The printer that I'm using is 203dpi.

Comment: Similar to what @Hans Passant said, If your output device is 203 dpi and the output size is 4 x 6 inches, I would want to send an image which is 812 x 1218, not 377 x 566. Again, I think you might tighten your development loop by doing so from some graphic program, then when that works well, getting your program to generate a graphic with the same image parameters.